# How to read the error from the response given by Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, error-messages, httpresponse

I have an api that has a catch method:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    // Error
    System.debug('API - ERROR: ' + e.getMessage()); 
    res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('ERROR: ' + e.getMessage());
    res.statusCode = 500;
}
```

As you can see, I put the error in the response body. However, when I read this response from Postman or another client, the body is empty and the status code is 500... How do you set the response error so that I can actually read what the error is?

Comment: Have you looked into using `setBody()`? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm

Comment: RestResponse does not have a `setBody()` method. I get the error `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setBody() from the type System.RestResponse`

Comment: Might want to specify that you are using RestResponse and not HttpResponse

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of a HttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

If your function's return type is not `void`, then you'd get back whatever you returned rather than `responseBody`. You cannot use a non-`void` return type and `responseBody` at the same time.

```
@HttpWhatever
public static void doAction() {
  // ...
  RestContext.response.responseBody = ...
```

---

... or ...

```
@HttpWhatever
public static String doAction() {
  // ...
  return 'Error: '+e.getMessage();
  // ...
```

Comment: So RestResponse does absolutely nothing other than set the statusCode?... What is the point of having RestResponse if the only thing that it works for is statusCode?

Comment: @BlondeSwan RestResponse works when you have a `void` return type. There are two methods for returning a value: automatic serialization via a return value, or manual serialization via responseBody. The automatic serialization takes priority over the manual serialization.

Comment: I have a `void` return type and am using `RestResponse`, but it's only good for status code? The RestResponse.response body does absolutely nothing for a client hitting the endpoint?

Comment: @BlondeSwan Without seeing more of your code, hard to tell much of anything. Make sure you're using the RestResponse provided by RestContext. If you construct your own, it won't work as you expect.

Comment: I am using the rest response provided by Rest Context:

```
RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
```
Is my declaration, and if something errors my catch statement I showed above is the last line of that method

Comment: @BlondeSwan It should work then... again, there's something off with your code. I've used responseBody plenty of times. It does work. You may want to post more of your code. Consider writing a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that we can copy-paste that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I was able to confirm that Postman gets the body as expected. We are making the call from Drupal, and printing out the response doesn't show the body. I'm confirming that our error is stemming from Drupal's handling of the response (because Drupal is trash)

Comment: @BlondeSwan you're welcome!